# SQL query with dynamic columns and dynamic data

Tags: sql, oracle

My query.

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'HEADER') VALUES
(SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'ITEMS')
```

In this query I am trying to insert data into TARGET_TABLE.
TABLE_DATA will have data in the below format

```
SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'HEADER'
Result COUNTRY,ID,NAME

SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'ITEMS'
Result 'IN','123','xyz'
```

So I am expecting the below

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (COUNTRY,ID,NAME) VALUES ('IN','123','xyz')
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Any Inputs / Suggestions on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

`select case` is what you need

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE 
(SELECT case when type='HEADER' then COL1 else 'aa' END
     ,case when type='HEADER' then COL2 else 'bb' END
     ,case when type='HEADER' then COL3 else 'cc' END
     ,case when type='HEADER' then COL4 else 'dd' END
FROM TABLE_DATA )
```

Comment: Nope, I am trying to achieve dynamic data, but in your case you are hard coding the columns

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a dynamic query like the following:

```
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
  'INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE ( ' 
  || SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'HEADER' 
  || ') VALUES ('
  || SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'ITEMS' 
  || ')';
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks for your response,
However when I use the below

<pre><code>
INSERT INTO TARGET (SELECT REPLACE( RAW_DATA,' ',',') FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE ROW_NO = 1) 
VALUES
(SELECT ''''|| REPLACE( RAW_DATA,' ',''',''') ||'''' FROM  TABLE_DATA WHERE ROW_NO <> 1) 
</code></pre>

Its giving error missing SELECT keyword.

Comment: I am not sure which platform you are executing the query. If you execute the code from my answer on SQL*Plus or SQL Developer then you will be able to achieve the desired result and then you need to convert the code to what is supported in your platform.

Comment: I am executing in SQL Developer

Comment: What is the result of the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE ( ' 
  || SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'HEADER' 
  || ') VALUES ('
  || SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'ITEMS' 
  || ')');`

Comment: Its just  as the below

'INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE ( ' || SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'HEADER' || ') VALUES (' || SELECT DATA FROM TABLE_DATA WHERE TYPE = 'ITEMS' || ')'

Comment: I don't think that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` can give you this result

Comment: its giving the same, anyway i found work around, used regex_substr and concatenated and inserted the data.